# Studying the differentiability of a function at a point $(a_{1},a_{2})$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have a function $\ f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ to study:

1) It's continuity at the point $(a_1,a_2)$.

2) The partial derivative exists at $(a_1,a_2)$?

3) Are the partial derivatives continuous in this point?

Here's what I do:

1) If $\lim_{(x,y)\to (a_1,a_2)} f$ it's equal to $f(a_1,a_2)$, then $f$ is continuous on that given point.

2)Here I calculate \begin{equation}
\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a_1+h,a_2)-f(a_1,a_2)}{\lVert h \rVert}=L_1
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\lim_{k \to 0} \frac{f(a_1,a_2+k)-f(a_1,a_2)}{\lVert h \rVert}=L_2
\end{equation}

If $L_1$ and $L_2$ are real numbers, partial derivatives exists.

3) Here I can see by the definition of differenciability of a function at a point if $f$ is differentiable, so the partial derivatives must be continuous on $(a_1,a_2)$. But there's some more way to see that the partial are continuous? Something like if  $L_1=L_2$, then the partial derivatives on $(a_1,a_2)$ are continuous, or something like that.

Thank you!

Comment: (3) is false. Continuous partial derivatives $\implies$ differentiability.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but how do you look that the partial derivatives are continuous?

Comment: $f$ is some *concrete* function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first two answers are ok, appart from the typo in the second limit. Also, since $h$ and $k$ in the limits are real numbers, you should write $|h|$ in the denominator, not $||h||$, since $||.||$ denotes a norm, you just need an absolute value (which is also a norm, but writing $||x||$ makes people think that $x$ is an element of $\mathbb R^n$ for $n>1$ which is not the case here).

For (3), your answer is not correct. To answer (3), you need to actually calculate the partial derivatives of $f$, at least around the point $(a_1,a_2)$, and then use the same step as (1) to show that they are continuous.

For example, if $f(x,y)=x^2+2xy+2y^2$ and $(a_1,a_2)=(0,0)$, then the partial derivatives of $f$ are $f_x=2x+2y$ and $f_y=2x+4y$, and since

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f_x(x,y) = \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} 2(x+y) = 0 = f_x(0,0)$$

$f_x$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 0):

1 is correct. However in many cases continuity can be derived by seeing that the function is a composition of continuous functions.

2 is not correct. There is no norm in the denominator (not even an absolute value as pointed in the other answer). Partial derivatives are the usual derivatives of a function with respect to one of the variables when all other variables are kept fixed. Hence you can apply all rules you have learned for functions of one variable, to compute the partial derivatives. If you want to use the definition (limit) here is the correct form:
$$
f_x(x,y) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}\\
f_y(x,y) = \lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(x,y+k)-f(x,y)}{k}
$$

3 Partial derivatives are functions of two variables. Hence you study continuity as in point 1.